# jQuery Ajax request returns null JSON only in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, asp.net-mvc-2, jquery-plugins

I am making a jQuery Ajax request to an ASP.NET MVC controller using the jQuery Form plugin.

The call works fine, but when I'm parsing the expected JSON I get the expected result in Firefox, but I get null in Internet Explorer.

The Ajax call is like this:

```
var options = {
    iframe: true,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (result, status) {
        $.unblockUI();
        _editingEmail = false;

        if (result.Sent === true) {
            ... Do something
        }

        $("#messageSentResult").html("<div>" + result.Message + "</div>");
    },
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        $.unblockUI();
        alert(textStatus);
    },
    beforeSubmit: function () {
        $.blockUI({
            message: '<h1>Processing...</h1>'
        });
    }
};

$('#myForm').ajaxForm(options);
```

This is my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public FileUploadJsonResult MyMethod()
{
    ... Do something

    if(ValidationFails())
    {
        return new FileUploadJsonResult { Data = new { Sent = false, Message = "The operation was not successful." } };
    }

    return new FileUploadJsonResult { Data = new { Sent = true, Message = "The operation succeeded." } };
}
```

The FileUploadJsonResult class looks like this:

```
public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
{
    this.ContentType = "text/html";
    context.HttpContext.Response.Write("<textarea>");
    base.ExecuteResult(context);
    context.HttpContext.Response.Write("</textarea>");
}
```

Comment: If I change the return type of the controller method to a regular JsonResult, both IE and Firefox ask me if I want to save or open the returned value which is not what I want but, at least the content is being returned to IE.

Comment: I have the same issue, did you resolve this?

Comment: @MarkRedman: This was too long ago. I seem to remember it turned out to be an issue with the jQuery library and the plugin clashing. Somebody in the office actually modified something on the plugin, checked it in and then it worked. Unfortunately I do not know exactly what he did.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, It seemed to work for after creating an inline function for the callback rather than specifying an external function.

Answer (score 2):

You should check that your HTML page has no errors and no warnings and set the ajax configuration to:

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting `cache: false` in your options?  By default, IE caches GET requests, which is what `.ajax()` uses, unless otherwise specified.  This could be causing your problem.

EDIT:

Have you tried changing the ContentType to `application/json`?  Like so:

```
public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
{
    this.ContentType = "application/json";
    context.HttpContext.Response.Write("<textarea>");
    base.ExecuteResult(context);
    context.HttpContext.Response.Write("</textarea>");
}
```

Comment: I do have $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); just before the options. I tried adding it to the options but got the same result.